# C++ Array bound exception on overflow - "cout" and no "cout"

Tags: c++, arrays, crash

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int array1[10] = {0};
  char* array2[10] = {'\0'};

  for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
  {
    std::cout << array1[i];   // This does not crash 
    //std::cout << array2[i]; // This crashes
    array1[i]; // Wont crash here
    array2[i]; // nor here, Why? because there is no cout??
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Ok so for the people answering here, i know i deliberately made an overflow for the arrays.  So why does the program crash on "cout", but not otherwise??

Thanks!

Comment: @Fred,Johannes OK so how about now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: In response to the *changed* version of the question, the reason it crashes for `array2` but not `array1` is that (at least under MSVC) the `operator<<` for `char*` tries to get the length of the pointed-to string and ends up dereferencing a `NULL` pointer. You get the same behaviour if you do:

```
std::cout << (char*)NULL;
```

The crash in this case is not caused by the out-of-bounds access, but by a null pointer dereference.

---

Despite that, further to what @UncleZeiv said, you can tell what code's actually doing by looking at the disassembly output from your compiler. For instance, on VC++ 2008, I get:

```
        std::cout<<array1[i]; //--> This crashes
00B2151E  mov         esi,esp 
00B21520  mov         eax,dword ptr [i] 
00B21523  mov         ecx,dword ptr array1[eax*4] 
00B21527  push        ecx  
00B21528  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (0B2A334h)] 
00B2152E  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (0B2A318h)] 
00B21534  cmp         esi,esp 
00B21536  call        @ILT+405(__RTC_CheckEsp) (0B2119Ah) 
        std::cout<<array2[i]; //--> So does this
00B2153B  mov         eax,dword ptr [i] 
00B2153E  mov         ecx,dword ptr array2[eax*4] 
00B21542  push        ecx  
00B21543  mov         edx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (0B2A334h)] 
00B21549  push        edx  
00B2154A  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (0B2114Fh) 
00B2154F  add         esp,8 
        array1[i]; // But not this one
        array2[i]; // nor this, Why?
```

In other words, the compiler is not outputting any instructions when you're not doing anything with `array1[i]` and `array2[i]` (the two instructions are no-ops), so the program doesn't crash even though you're theoretically referencing something beyond the bounds of the array and invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: You are so right! May be you can edit your answer a bit for my question's edition.

Comment: Note that VC++ does *not* optimize anything away. The semantics for `array1[i]` and `array2[i]` is that it doesn't read anything. It just builds up an array index expression, and then nothing else happens. So there is no reason to optimize anything.

Comment: @litb: but couldn't it theoretically optimize it in this case? In general `operator []` could have some other effect so it shouldn't be *always* optimized away, but here?

Comment: @UncleZeiv: I'll let Johannes answer for himself, but for what it's worth, my take on it is that he's right in this case because we're talking about arrays -- the point is that no optimization needs to happen, `arr[i];` where `arr` is an array just naturally doesn't generate any code. If we were talking about a type with an `operator[]`, that would not be the case -- in that case, the compiler might be able to optimize it away if and only if it could prove that the `operator[]` did not have side-effects, but that would at least involve an optimization step. Here, no such step is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Given that the value is unused, it is probably optimized away by the compiler and never really retrieved at run time.

Comment: Probably right so +1. The important point to note is that undefined behaviour means _exactly_ that: undefined. It may work, it may not. It may work depending on the phase of the moon for all we know. Don't do it!

Comment: If the value is declared and defined properly than why cant it be printed?It might be that after 10 iterations it points somewhere where it might not be able to print the values.Some what like paxdiable said.